# Command button to return user back to source workbook

Tags: vba, excel

We have a userform that pops-up and remains on top of all applications.

Since users are always working on multiple workbooks and applications, I want a button on the userform. On clicking this button the users should be returned to the workbook from where the userform is activated.

Let's say the userform is activated from Book1. On clicking the button, users should be returned to book1.

I'm just an excel beginner. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Activate`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in the code for the userform:

```
Public wbSource As Workbook

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    wbSource.Activate
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
End Sub
```

Comment: `wbSource` is superfluous here. If you're assigning it as `ThisWorkbook`, just use `ThisWorkbook.Activate`.

Comment: There may be some (advanced) situations where it's unsafe to assume `ThisWorkbook` is the one which launched the UserForm, and those cases could be handled e.g., `Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook 'etc...` but if OP was writing code for scenarios that advanced, it's unlikely s/he would have to ask how to do this :)